# batch file to open two (or more) powershells in two (or more) specific folders

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to do something really basic in a batch script, but it is not working.

I want to open two PowerShell windows each with a different current working directory.

I am using the following script

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command "cd c:\Users\User1" 
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command "cd c:\Users\User2"
```

Unfortunately it opens only the first window.

For sure it is only a syntax error but I could not find a solution yet.

Comment: `cd C:\…` should read `cd /D C:\…` in order to also change the drive if necessary…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it happens often: I posted the question after researching a lot and then I immediately found the answer!

This is what you should write in your batch file:

```
START C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command "cd c:\Users\User1" 
START C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command "cd c:\Users\User2"
```

I hope my answer will help someone in the same situation.

Answer (score 2):

The `Start` command already has a 'working directory', option, `/D`.

```sh
@Start /D "C:\Users\User1" %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit
@Start /D "C:\Users\User2" %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit
```

You could of course do it with a simple `For` loop:

```sh
@For %%G In ("C:\Users\User1" "C:\Users\User2") Do @Start /D "%%~G" %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
start C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command "cd c:\Users\User1"
start C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command "cd c:\Users\User2"
```

You just need to add "start" at the beginning

Comment: If you not add start, then it does open it in the same terminal as the batch file